# Pointer memory representation and Inheritance casting

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, memory, casting

I was playing around single/multiple inheritance when I noticed that the reinterpret cast works just as well as static cast when downcasting a pointer to an object higher up in the class hierarchy to a pointer to its underlying type.

I'm not very good with words so to see what I'm trying to say, consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class A {
public:
  A (void) {
  }
  virtual ~A (void) noexcept {
  }
  virtual void ABehaviour (void) const {
    std::cout << "Behaviour of Object A implemented in Object A.\n";
  } 
};

class B : public A {
public:  
  B (void) 
    : A () {
  }
  ~B (void) noexcept override {
  }
  void ABehaviour (void) const override {
    std::cout << "Behaviour of Object A implemented in Object B.\n";
  }
  void BBehaviour (void) const {
    std::cout << "Behaviour of Object B implemented in Object B.\n";
  }
};

int main (int arg_count, char* arg_vector[]) {
  B* b_object1 = new B (); // Create an object B.
  b_object1->ABehaviour (); // This line works fine.
  b_object1->BBehaviour (); // This line works fine.

  A* a_object1 = b_object1 // Implicit Upcast to Object A.
  a_object1->ABehaviour (); // This line works fine.
  a_object1->BBehaviour (); // This is a compile time error.

  B* b_object2 = reinterinpret_cast <B*> (a_object1);
  b_object2->ABehaviour (); // This line works fine.
  b_object2->BBehaviour (); // This line works fine.

  delete b_object1;
  b_object1 = nullptr;
  a_object1 = nullptr;
  b_object2 = nullptr;

  return 0;
}
```

Intuitively, the above cast should work as it is similar to calling:

```
B* b_object2 = static_cast <B*> (static_cast <void*> (a_object1));
```

From what I've read, reinterpret_cast is a compiler directive that tells the compiler to interpret the object-being-casted's sequence of bits to a sequence of bits of the object-being-casted-to's. In the above case A* is being reinterpreted as B*.

From what I've understood when I took an introductory course in C++ a long time ago is that pointers are variables themselves that contains addresses to other variables. Hence, when the above reinterpret cast is executed, the compiler is told to interpret the pointer to A's sequence of bits as if it was a pointer to B's sequence of bits (not their content themselves).

So my question is, are my intuitions right or does the internal working of a pointer when casting a little bit different. If I was wrong would anyone care to explain how are pointers stored in the memory and how does their casting work (both up and down) internally?

Sorry about the wall of text and thank you guys in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`a_object1` is a pointer pointing to an object of type `A`. So it only has access to `A`'s methods.

Your understanding of pointers is right too. Pointers just hold the address of the object it is pointing to. So the pointer in itself doesn't have a type. When I say a pointer of type A, I mean a pointer that points to `A` (or a subclass of `A`).

---

`A* a_object1 = b_object1` is the same as doing `static_cast<A*> (b_object1)`.

If you want call `BBehaviour()` a_object1, you'll have to do `static_cast<B*>(a_object1)->BBehaviour()`. It'll work in this case because though `a_object1` is of type `A*` it points to an object with runtime-type `B*`.

Code like `static_cast<B*>(a_object1)->BBehaviour()` is a sign of bad design BTW, so you want to avoid that. (If you need to do it, you'll use `dynamic_cast` here.)

`reinterpret_cast<>()` can, on the other hand, change any object to any other unrelated object. For example:

```
std::string str = reinterpret_cast<std::string>(a_object1)
```

will compile fine, but you'll have problems while running it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I am still unsure as to how such cast works internally. If I am not wrong, pointers have their own addresses (just like a normal variables), hence, when I perform a reinterpret downcast, such sequence of bits of A (its memory representation) is interpreted as B. Since this is a compiler directive, the memory structure is not affected. But how is this "compiler reinterpreting" performed?

Comment: @R34 the type of a pointer tells the compiler how many bits (starting from the pointed to address) it should take and interpret as a given type.

Comment: Thanks for the design advice. I'll take a note of that. But this still doesn't answer my question of how it works internally (I mean memory level). I am aware that the above code is badly designed but that is besides the point as it is only meant to be an example.

Comment: @UnholySheep Ahh I see. Correct me if I'm wrong but from what I understood, when I perform reinterpret cast on a pointer, the address that it points to get's changed (depending on the implementation) and the vpointer it has will point to the vtable of the object it is casted to? Thanks for your reply :D

Comment: @R34 UnholySheep has answered that. Let's say A takes 2 blocks of memory. And B takes one additional block of memory (total 3). This memory is allocated in the heap. A* pointer will take the first two blocks, while B* will use all the 3 blocks.

Comment: @R34 when you cast nothing happens. You're just telling the compiler to tell start believing an object of type X to be an object of type Y.

Comment: @R34 for example, if have bytes `0x48492100` in memory, if `int*` points to that data, this is number 2181448, if you `reinterpret_cast` that pointer to `char*`, it would mean _"HI!"_, even though underlying bytes stays the same

Comment: @gldraphael Ah I'm aware of that too. However, I though classes have fixed size for alignment purposes?

Comment: @R34 I'm really not the right person who can help you with internals. Though I'm aware that alignment is done for each member (not for the class as a whole), and that it's an implementation detail. UnholySheep/Revolver_Ocelot correct me if I'm wrong 

Comment: Thank you guys so much having this discussion with me. I will need time to do more tests and organize my thoughts. I will hopefully update my post if something significant comes up.